# Appcelerator - Get device volume in Android

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I want to get the android device volume. In iOS exists this property `Ti.Media.volume` but in Android doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be good to create a feature request at [Appcelerator's JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org) to get this API on par for Android.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen I don't know how to use JIRA. I'm sorry. I tried to create a reques but I can't

Comment: Please see this guide on how to use the Appcelerator JIRA: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/How_to_Submit_a_Bug_Report You can create an account via https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/Signup!default.jspa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can use [volume control](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/2634#!overview) module to control device volume for both android and iOS.